# time.sleep seems to block other threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have this simple Python 3 program where a child thread sleeps and the main thread seems to be blocked as well. Why doesn't `sleep` switch the cpu to the main thread?

```
import threading
import time


def hello():
    print('hello')
    while True:
        time.sleep(10000)


threading.Thread(hello()).start()

print('world')
```

Output:

```
hello
```

The word `world` never printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking `hello` on the main thread by using `hello()` this is a function call (because of the `()`), not a function reference. The reference (name) is just `hello`.

Maybe try:

```
threading.Thread(target=hello).start()
```